# Python remove '\n' from list and then convert strings in list to integers

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, integer

```
my_list = []
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath , newline='') as f:
    array1 = (line.split(',') for line in f.readlines())
    last_col = [line.split(',')[-1] for line in f]
    for line in array1:          
        my_list.append(line[-1])
```

This works but my_list has `\n` at the end of each line. How can I remove it. After I remove it how do I turn it into an integer list?
I've tried doing something like

```
list(map(int, my_list))
```

but I get an error because of the new lines.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Adj Close\n'
```

Comment: would something like `str.rstrip`\`str.strip` work?

Comment: It looks very much like you're trying to write a CSV-file parser by hand. Don't do that; just use the standard [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Don't just say "I get an error", please show us the error (with the traceback). And make sure that the code you've posted actually generates that error. And give us some (short) sample input that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want the last column as a list of integers.  Is that correct?  If so:

```
with open(datafile) as fin:
    last_column = [ int(line.split(',')[-1]) for line in fin ]
```

should do the trick...

If you want each row as a list of integers:

```
with open(datafile) as fin:
    rows = [ [int(x) for x in line.split(',')] for line in fin ]
    #same as
    #rows = [ list(map(int,line.split(','))) for line in fin ] #if you prefer ...
```

Note that in python, `int` will happily convert a string with any whitespace:

```
>>> print(int('\t\n300\n'))
300
```

so the newlines aren't a problem ... (tested using python3.2 and python2.7)

Comment: @user2018488 -- I find that hard to believe.  I can't see any way that `line` would be a `list` type in my above code...

Comment: @mgilson: In fact, I can't see how his _original_ code could fail in the way he describes, either. I suspect his input is now what it should be, and his error is not actually anything to do with the newlines.

Comment: @abarnert -- Yeah.  OP's original code is a bit annoying to unravel, but basically the problem is that by the time the generator is started for iteration, the file has already been consumed by the list-comprehension and so there's nothing left to iterate over -- I think this would leave `my_list` completely empty ... scratch that -- After seeing your edit it looks like `f.readlines()` is run when the generator is created ... *sigh* I wish python would remove `readlines` from the file object all together ...

Comment: @mgilson: They did remove `readlines`, you just need to upgrade to 3.x. (Of course `list(f)` does the same thing as `f.readlines()`, and it's still there… but nobody ever thinks that's what they want, except in the rare cases where it really _is_ what they want.)

Comment: @mgilson: By the way, the tricky bit here isn't really `readlines`; even if he used the normal iterator to popular `array1`, `last_col` would still be empty, and that would still be both a red herring (because it's never actually used, so it doesn't matter that it's empty) and a red flag (that the OP's code probably isn't what he posted).

Comment: @abarnert -- They got rid of f.readlines in 3.x?  Now that was a good decision.  I have 3.x, and I think about 2.x -> 3.x compatability all the time, but that's one I never learned about :)

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, it was eliminated as part of the iteratorization of everything—just as `map` became `imap`, `range` became `xrange`, etc., `readlines` became… nothing, because `xreadlines` had already been removed. (Also, there is no "file object" in 2.x terms anymore; `open` returns an object of private type that implements the appropriate ABC from the `io` module, normally meaning `TextIOBase` and `BufferedIOBase`. See http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy for details. This makes it much cleaner, but also harder to explain things to new users…)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse CSV files, you don't want to have to deal with all the fiddly cases like newlines in the last column, spaces around the commas, etc. Just use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module that comes with Python:

```
my_list = []
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath) as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        numbers = list(map(int, row))
        my_list.append(line[-1])
```

Or, possibly more simply:

```
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath) as f:
    my_list = [list(map(int, row)) for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

Mixing a list comprehension and a `map` onto one line looks a bit surprising to me, but in this case, I think it looks a little better than the pure comprehension alternative:

```
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath) as f:
    my_list = [[int(col) for col in row] for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

And a lot better than the pure functional alternative:

```
my_list = list(map(compose(list, partial(map, int)), 
                   csv.reader(iterwith(open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code works just fine for what you're trying to do.

To make it self-contained, I moved the file into the program as a `StringIO`, but otherwise, this is your code, word for word:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO('''1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
''')

my_list = []
array1 = (line.split(',') for line in f.readlines())
last_col = [line.split(',')[-1] for line in f]
for line in array1:          
    my_list.append(line[-1])

print(list(map(int, my_list)))
```

And here's what it does:

```
[3, 6]
```

Which is exactly what you wanted, right?

So, if it's not working, it's not because of the newlines; it's because of something else. And, since you never told us what the error is, or anything about it beyond "I get an error because of the new lines", nobody can possibly guess what that something else might be. Maybe you've got a `3.6` in there, and you're getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.6'`. Maybe you have no file at the specified path, and you're getting a `FileNotFoundError` error. Maybe you forgot a shebang and you're running your Python 3.x script with a Python 2 interpreter, or with bash. Anything's possible, based on what you've told us.

Comment: My best guess is that the file has a blank line at the end, and the error message we haven't seen is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'`, but who can say?  Could also be an extra `,` at the end of a line or something, too, but guessing probably isn't very productive..